# Laravel 5.2 ERROR HTTP 302

Tags: laravel-5

I'm use laravel 5.2 Now, In server alert "Apache Web Server HTTP Error 302 - Moved temporarily"

I try to use. this code below in Handler but this alert still happen. 
How I can do with this problem? Thank you for your help.

```
        public function render($request, Exception $e) {

        if($this->isHttpException($e)) {
        switch ($e->getStatusCode()) { 
        // not found 
        case 404: return 
        redirect()->guest('/'); break;

        // internal error
        case '500':
        return redirect()->guest('/');
        break;

        case 302:
        return redirect()->guest('/');
        break;

        default:
            return $this->renderHttpException($e);
        break;
    }
    }
       else
    {
          return parent::render($request, $e);
   }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a low level error triggered by Apache, not PHP. So the error never reaches Laravel in order for it to handle the error.

Check out how to customize error pages for Apache [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html).

In your Apache configuration; add a line similar to the below:

```
ErrorDocument 302 "Sorry, site is moved temporarily"
```